# Rails running methods inappropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

A rails controller defines a before_action

```
  before_action :set_intervento, only: [ ... ]
```

to

```
def set_intervento
  @intervento = Intervento.find(params[:id])
end
```

But my action `risultati_fatturati` is not listed in the `only` block.  yet error `Couldn't find Intervento with 'id'=risultati_fatturati`is being generated where Rails justifying itself as having to run the set_intervento method.  What else is at work here that is launching the method?

**EDIT**
routes show

```
  resources :interventos do
    collection do
      get :indexmio
      get :indexmio_programmati
      get :passati
      get :non_assegnati
      get :programmati
      get :domani
      get :domani_e_dopo
      get :settimana
      get :planning
      get :in_corso
      get :successivi
      get :successivo
      get :passati_da_eseguire
      get :articolo_adhoc
      get :calendar
      post :calendarc
      get :settimanale
      get  :chiusi
      post :ripresa
      get :risultati_articolos
      get :risultati_ordina_articolos
      get :creare_checklist
      post :neuter_ddt
      post :cancel_ddt
      get  :elenco_ddt
      get  :dispatcher_check
      get  :manager_list
      get  :manager_comments
      post :manager_check_required
      get  :preventivi_attivi
      get  :cerca_fatturati
      get  :non_fatturabili
      post :risultati_fatturati
      get  :cerca_chiusi
      post :risultati_chiusi
      post :duplicate_intervento
      get  :ordinari_chiusi
      get  :ordinari_aperti
    end
    member do
      get   :pdfc
      get   :create_pdf_rapporto
      get   :refresh_pause_intervento
      get   :refresh_close_intervento
      patch :update_successivo
      patch :update_ddt
      patch :materials_sucessivo
      patch :materials_availability
      patch :preventivare
      patch :esito_preventivo
      patch :scaduto_preventivo
      patch :ripristina_preventivo
      get   :dispatcher_fix
      patch :dispatcher_signature
      get   :correzione_fattura
    end
  end
```

Translating to

```
                   indexmio_interventos GET    /interventos/indexmio(.:format)                     interventos#indexmio
        indexmio_programmati_interventos GET    /interventos/indexmio_programmati(.:format)         interventos#indexmio_programmati
                     passati_interventos GET    /interventos/passati(.:format)                      interventos#passati
               non_assegnati_interventos GET    /interventos/non_assegnati(.:format)                interventos#non_assegnati
                 programmati_interventos GET    /interventos/programmati(.:format)                  interventos#programmati
                      domani_interventos GET    /interventos/domani(.:format)                       interventos#domani
               domani_e_dopo_interventos GET    /interventos/domani_e_dopo(.:format)                interventos#domani_e_dopo
                   settimana_interventos GET    /interventos/settimana(.:format)                    interventos#settimana
                    planning_interventos GET    /interventos/planning(.:format)                     interventos#planning
                    in_corso_interventos GET    /interventos/in_corso(.:format)                     interventos#in_corso
                  successivi_interventos GET    /interventos/successivi(.:format)                   interventos#successivi
                  successivo_interventos GET    /interventos/successivo(.:format)                   interventos#successivo
         passati_da_eseguire_interventos GET    /interventos/passati_da_eseguire(.:format)          interventos#passati_da_eseguire
              articolo_adhoc_interventos GET    /interventos/articolo_adhoc(.:format)               interventos#articolo_adhoc
                    calendar_interventos GET    /interventos/calendar(.:format)                     interventos#calendar
                   calendarc_interventos POST   /interventos/calendarc(.:format)                    interventos#calendarc
                 settimanale_interventos GET    /interventos/settimanale(.:format)                  interventos#settimanale
                      chiusi_interventos GET    /interventos/chiusi(.:format)                       interventos#chiusi
                     ripresa_interventos POST   /interventos/ripresa(.:format)                      interventos#ripresa
         risultati_articolos_interventos GET    /interventos/risultati_articolos(.:format)          interventos#risultati_articolos
  risultati_ordina_articolos_interventos GET    /interventos/risultati_ordina_articolos(.:format)   interventos#risultati_ordina_articolos
            creare_checklist_interventos GET    /interventos/creare_checklist(.:format)             interventos#creare_checklist
                  neuter_ddt_interventos POST   /interventos/neuter_ddt(.:format)                   interventos#neuter_ddt
                  cancel_ddt_interventos POST   /interventos/cancel_ddt(.:format)                   interventos#cancel_ddt
                  elenco_ddt_interventos GET    /interventos/elenco_ddt(.:format)                   interventos#elenco_ddt
            dispatcher_check_interventos GET    /interventos/dispatcher_check(.:format)             interventos#dispatcher_check
                manager_list_interventos GET    /interventos/manager_list(.:format)                 interventos#manager_list
            manager_comments_interventos GET    /interventos/manager_comments(.:format)             interventos#manager_comments
      manager_check_required_interventos POST   /interventos/manager_check_required(.:format)       interventos#manager_check_required
           preventivi_attivi_interventos GET    /interventos/preventivi_attivi(.:format)            interventos#preventivi_attivi
             cerca_fatturati_interventos GET    /interventos/cerca_fatturati(.:format)              interventos#cerca_fatturati
             non_fatturabili_interventos GET    /interventos/non_fatturabili(.:format)              interventos#non_fatturabili
         risultati_fatturati_interventos POST   /interventos/risultati_fatturati(.:format)          interventos#risultati_fatturati
                cerca_chiusi_interventos GET    /interventos/cerca_chiusi(.:format)                 interventos#cerca_chiusi
            risultati_chiusi_interventos POST   /interventos/risultati_chiusi(.:format)             interventos#risultati_chiusi
        duplicate_intervento_interventos POST   /interventos/duplicate_intervento(.:format)         interventos#duplicate_intervento
             ordinari_chiusi_interventos GET    /interventos/ordinari_chiusi(.:format)              interventos#ordinari_chiusi
             ordinari_aperti_interventos GET    /interventos/ordinari_aperti(.:format)              interventos#ordinari_aperti
                         pdfc_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/pdfc(.:format)                     interventos#pdfc
          create_pdf_rapporto_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/create_pdf_rapporto(.:format)      interventos#create_pdf_rapporto
     refresh_pause_intervento_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/refresh_pause_intervento(.:format) interventos#refresh_pause_intervento
     refresh_close_intervento_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/refresh_close_intervento(.:format) interventos#refresh_close_intervento
            update_successivo_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/update_successivo(.:format)        interventos#update_successivo
                   update_ddt_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/update_ddt(.:format)               interventos#update_ddt
          materials_sucessivo_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/materials_sucessivo(.:format)      interventos#materials_sucessivo
       materials_availability_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/materials_availability(.:format)   interventos#materials_availability
                 preventivare_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/preventivare(.:format)             interventos#preventivare
             esito_preventivo_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/esito_preventivo(.:format)         interventos#esito_preventivo
           scaduto_preventivo_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/scaduto_preventivo(.:format)       interventos#scaduto_preventivo
        ripristina_preventivo_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/ripristina_preventivo(.:format)    interventos#ripristina_preventivo
               dispatcher_fix_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/dispatcher_fix(.:format)           interventos#dispatcher_fix
         dispatcher_signature_intervento PATCH  /interventos/:id/dispatcher_signature(.:format)     interventos#dispatcher_signature
           correzione_fattura_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/correzione_fattura(.:format)       interventos#correzione_fattura
                             interventos GET    /interventos(.:format)                              interventos#index
                                         POST   /interventos(.:format)                              interventos#create
                          new_intervento GET    /interventos/new(.:format)                          interventos#new
                         edit_intervento GET    /interventos/:id/edit(.:format)                     interventos#edit
                              intervento GET    /interventos/:id(.:format)                          interventos#show
                                         PATCH  /interventos/:id(.:format)                          interventos#update
                                         PUT    /interventos/:id(.:format)                          interventos#update
                                         DELETE /interventos/:id(.:format)                          interventos#destroy
```

and the controller action

```
  def risultati_fatturati
    date = params[:intervento]
    @date_start = Date.civil(date["dal(1i)"].to_i, date["dal(2i)"].to_i, date["dal(3i)"].to_i)
    @date_end   = Date.civil(date["al(1i)"].to_i, date["al(2i)"].to_i, date["al(3i)"].to_i)
    if !params[:intervento][:invoicestate_id].blank?
      @interventos = Intervento.joins(:signatures).where(['signatures.created_at >= ? AND signatures.created_at <= ? AND signatures.sequence = ? AND interventos.invoicestate_id = ?', @date_start.at_beginning_of_day, @date_end.at_end_of_day, "fine", params[:intervento][:invoicestate_id]]).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 100
    else
      @interventos = Intervento.joins(:signatures).where(['signatures.created_at >= ? AND signatures.created_at <= ? AND signatures.sequence = ?', @date_start.at_beginning_of_day, @date_end.at_end_of_day, "fine"]).paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 100
    end
    render layout: "application"
  end
```

so the action is within a collection and does not call `@intervento`.  This is why I find it strange.

**Edit #2**

*Side note: attempted to remove the before_action and find the member in each action, leading to identical results. Thus there is a deeper cause.*

In an attempt to view things differently and understand via triangulation, I attempted a theoretically simpler process.  That of running a partial for updating each record

```
<%= render "stato_fatturazione", intervento: intervento %>
```

whose form calls a specific action, which will invoke Rails's ujs

```
<%= form_for stato_fatturazione_intervento_path(intervento), method: :patch, remote: true, data: {disable_with: "Aggiornando..."} do |f| %>
```

Alas, notwithstanding the parameters, that have the proper path for editing, rails is attempting to patch the page with the array of records, which is by definition unpatchable, and leads to the same `Couldn't find Intervento with 'id'=risultati_fatturati`

```
Started PATCH "/interventos/risultati_fatturati" for ::1 at 2017-07-31 10:52:14 +0200
Processing by InterventosController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "/interventos/123/stato_fatturazione"=>{"invoicestate_id"=>"3", "in_zucchetti"=>"475", "fatturato"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Aggiorna", "id"=>"risultati_fatturati"}
```

The rendered HTML does confirm the target action is being intercepted by some method:

```
<form data-disable-with="Aggiornando..." action="/interventos/risultati_fatturati" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
```

Comment: My advice is to put a binding.pry on the set_intervento method and run "caller" that method is going to output the stack of calls up to that point.
You'll need the pry gem to run this. You'll see whos calling it.

Comment: Can you share the code for `risultati_fatturati` please? Hard to tell what's going on without seeing its implementation.

Comment: Could be many things. Do you have the right routes in place? Have you overridden `to_params` in any of your models? Hard to say with the limited code provided here.

Comment: I think you need to show the full routes under `resources :interventos` and maybe publish your rake routes.  It looks like the path `http://localhost:3000/interventos/risultati_fatturati` is being intercepted by the `interventos/:id` route, so the member routes are matching before the collection routes.

Comment: You can get around this with brute force... make the top line of your routes to be `post 'interventos/risultati_fatturati', action: 'interventos#risultati_fatturati'` and that will fix it, but there's a more elegant fix if you showed your routes properly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `risultati_fatturati` method, it's just that your regular member post route is intercepting the call and you never get to the method.

Comment: Updated the routes block for the controller.  Sorry, it is a biggie...  I wonder whether the member block should be before the collection block... as this is not the first time I've seen the symptom...

Comment: No, collection should be before member.  It looks ok, I can't see a problem... try adding `gem 'pry'` to your Gemfile and then ApplicationController add `before_action :debug_input`  and then have `def debug_input; binding.pry; end` in the controller.

Comment: That will let you halt inspect every input (type "params" to see the params) and you want to see what action is being called for your `risultati_fatturati` url.  When you're ready to proceed type `exit`  and (of course) once it's all debugged you can remove the `before_action`

Comment: had tried byebug. pry is new to me.  I did not get far, but updated the question which may enlighten a bit...